# Given that \$Q = {R} {\sqrt{L/C}}\$, why not maximise Q by setting L huge and C tiny?

Tags: rf, resonance

For the tank circuit below, the resonant frequency is f0=10kHz, where:

$$
f0=1/(2 \pi \sqrt{L_1 C_1}).
$$

Assuming R=1 ohm, and given that [correction thanks to @Franc]
$$
Q_1 = \frac{R} {\sqrt{L_1/C_1}},
$$
the value of Q for the circuit below comes to 6,287.

If I want to maximise Q, I could just increase the inductance by a factor of 10 and decrease the capacitance by a factor of 10, which defines L2=1000mH and C2=0.253nF. The resonant frequency remains the same at f0=10kHz but the quality Q has increased to Q2 = 62,870.

Why is it a bad idea to just keep increasing the ratio L/C? What are the costs of doing so?

So the numbers above are wrong, but the general question about changing the ratio L/C while keeping the product LC constant remains.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frcyf4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Schematically, where is R? What connects to the tank (it makes a huge difference).

Comment: Q is also equal to Qo=wo*L/R ... And DC_R is greater than 1 Ohm ... without "skin" effect ...

Comment: Andy,  Good point. R is in series with L1.  The tank circuit is connected to a very high impedance (TL084) op amp.

Comment: What do you think happens to R when L is increased?

Comment: (I assume this is a helpful nudge question). I was assuming R is constant, but I realise (suspect)  L contributes to  R, in which case R is proportional to L. If so, increasing L increases Q, which (as @mathskeepmebusy says) will increase impedance (in addition to the increased contribution of R to impedance).

Comment: @JamesVStone then you are using the incorrect formula for q factor.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Having checked, the formula I used above for Q1 applies to a circuit in which L1, C1 and R are in parallel. So, I don't  know what happens to R when L increases.

Comment: More to the point, suppose the inductor is a spool of wire; what happens to R and L when you spool more wire onto it? There are other ways of varying inductance, but this suffices to show R might not be independent in practice :)

Comment: Yes, for example, in the circuit below C1 || (L1 + R1), by @mathskeepsmebusy.

Comment: Don't forget about the self resonant frequency (SRF) of the inductor. As you add more turns, the winding capacitance increases as well as the inductance which lowers the SRF. Also, the loss resistance increases with more turns. There are practical limitations to magnetics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Given that Q = R/sqrt(L/C), why not maximise Q by setting L huge and C tiny?

There are several issues to consider.

The first is the impedance of the tank network. Although the Q varies as \$\sqrt{L/C}\$ varies relative to R, so does the impedance. This means that the ratio between voltage and current in the tank changes. Typically, a tank network is found in an oscillator or in a class C amplifier. That oscillator or amplifier will typically powered by a power supply with a maximum or a fixed *voltage*. If the impedance goes too high, the current must go down, and the power with it. The situation is entirely analogous to that of choosing a collector resistor in a common emitter amplifier. The larger the collector resistor, the larger the possible *voltage* gain, but the smaller available power.

Another concern is parasitic reactances. As the capacitor becomes smaller, the inductance of the leads or traces for the capacitor start to contribute a greater share of the reactance in that branch of the circuit. Similarly, an inductor has capacitance between its turns. The more turns, generally, the more parasitic capacitance. Making the inductor too big and the capacitor too small means that the parasitic reactances will play a more significant role in determining the reactances in each branch. The transfer function of the tank circuit will become more complex and it will be much harder to *control* or predict the frequency response of the tank.

A third concern is the cost, bulk and weight of the inductor. Other things being equal, inductance increases with turns squared, while resistance increases directly with turns, *as long as the size of the turns and the size of the wire remain unchanged*. That means that as the inductance to resistance ratio goes up, the physical size of the inductor will generally need to be increased. It won't do to use thinner wires. So, the costs (in money, bulk and weight) change as the inductor / capacitor ratio is changed. To large an inductance (without making the wires smaller) generally will bring unfavorable economics.

---

> Please confirm you are referring to a circuit in which C,L and R are in parallel (which is the circuit I should have drawn for the equation Q=R sqrt(L/C) used above).

In the case where R is just the parasitic resistance of the inductor, and the inductor and capacitor are in parallel, we have a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f61rvN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the formula

$$Q \approx \frac{1}{R}\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$

applies.

My answer was based on the assumption of such a configuration. However, the results are valid in any case.

I actually did not notice this when I first read your question, but the formula you used originally in your question, and which I quoted in my answer, i.e. "Q = R/sqrt(L/C)" does not apply to a tank circuit, as shown above. At some point the equation was modified in edits, to "Q=R sqrt(L/C)". That is the same equation used in your comment. It does not apply to either a tank circuit in which R is just the parasitic resistance of the inductor, nor to the configuration in which C, L and R are all in parallel. For the latter configuration, the formula

$$Q \approx R\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}$$

applies. However, in that case, Q goes *down* (not up) when L is increased.

In any event, the effects of making L large and C small are accurately described in my answer. The impedance of an inductor goes up, the more inductance it has. The impedance of a capacitor goes up the *less* capacitance it has. The parasitic reactances play a larger role, making control and prediction of frequency response harder. The cost, bulk and weight, all increase by making L very large and C very small. But the Q goes *down* for the all parallel components configuration, and up for the series. (But making C very large and L very small comes with similar problems. Often, in engineering, finding a balance is key to a good design, and it is so in this case.

Comment: Thanks.  Please confirm you are referring to a circuit in which C,L and R are in parallel (which is the circuit I should have drawn for the equation Q=R sqrt(L/C) used above).

Comment: Sorry for making a pig's ear of this question. But, I think you have grasped the main point of my question, which is: We can alter the ratio L/C (and therefore Q) whilst keeping C*L (and therefore f0) constant, so why not just make L/C large? Your answer spells it out: As L/C increases, so does the impedance.

Comment: In your  circuit where C1 || (L1 + R1), for which Q = 1/R*sqrt(L/C), can we assume R = r+kL, where r is (small, fixed) wiring resistance (of the tank circuit, for example), and k is a constant which defines ohms/meter for the inductor? If so, this complicates the problem of maximising Q.

Comment: For a fixed diameter, wire resistance is proportional to length, but inductance is proportional to turns squared. Not sure how this complicates.

Comment: L/C is not constant fixed for a given frequency. L*C is fixed for a given frequency.

Comment: With correction ... If we define a=1 ohm/m as the resistance per metre of wire, r=0.01m as the resistance of wire in the tank circuit, and if L*C is constant (so f0 is constant) then Q = 1./(r+a*L) .* sqrt(L./C). A graph of Q vs L asymptotes for large values of L (250mH for the constants I assumed). So there are diminishing returns on Q as L is increased.

Comment: In general,  the ratio between R and L is not fixed. R increases proportionally with the length of wire, and inversely with the cross sectional area of the wire.  L increases with the square of the number of turns, provided the length of the inductor is not too long relative to its width. When turns are overlapped, the outer turns will have a longer length than the inner turns. But we can always change the resistance by changing the wire diameter. In general we can't say R is a linear function of L. It could just as easily be function of L^2 (as long as L doesn't vary too much.)

Comment: Thanks. Even taking account of L proportional to (number of turns)^2, I estimate Q is approximately proportional to sqrt(L).

Answer (score 0):

> ... why not maximize Q by setting L huge and C tiny?

Guess ... No OP "current" defined ...

Should be "difficult" to set a huge L.

Calculated with coil64, air inductor, multilayer, with 0.1 mm wire ...
Examples:
100 mH -> Rdc= 726 Ohm -> wo*L/R = 8.65 @10 kHz

1000 mH -> Rdc= 2374 Ohm -> wo*L/R = 26.5 @10 kHz

[image]

[image]

No parasitic capacitor into account ...
No "skin" effect calculated.

Comment: So, increasing L by a factor of 10 increased Q by a factor of 26.5/8.65 = 3 (approx).

Comment: Yes with the same wire used. But "skin" and "proximity" effects are not taken into account. I did not search for inductors with ferrite or something else that would be better for the resistors (lower). But current DC ... should also be "lower".